# Install font easily - product integral?

Tags: fonts, installing, ubuntu

Is there a way to install fonts easily from a tar.gz file?  I'm looking to install http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~gill/prodint.tgz.  The README states:

> 1. Copy "`prodint.tfm`" and "`prodint.pfb`" where the LaTeX fonts live.
> 2. Add to your "`fonts.map`" (usually in "`/usr/share/texmf/dvips/config`")
>      the entry:
>
>    ```
>    prodint prodint < prodint.pfb
>    ```
> 3. Copy "`prodint.sty`" where LaTeX can see it.
> 4. Execute ``mktexlsr`' or whatever you need to do to update the ls-R file.
>
> "`prodint.sty`" defines the product-integral symbol in three sizes:
>
> ```
> \prodi   ----- text
> \Prodi   ----- display
> \PRODI   ----- big
> ```
>
> check "`prodint.ps`" to see how these look like.
>
> You can generate "`prodint.ps`" without installing the LaTeX `prodint`
>
> files by typing
>
> ```
> latex prodint; dvips -o prodint.ps -P prodint prodint
> ```
>
> in this directory.

I'm on Ubuntu, and I'd like a process to install this easily whenever I'm on a new computer.    Or can I create a LaTeX package somehow so I can have this font installed easily? Additional information about further definition that I need to define in my LaTeX source file to get it working is here http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Product_integral.  I'd like to be able to do something like `\usepackage{prodint}` and be able to use the commands.  Let me know if this is possible.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I took the liberty and improved the formatting of your post. You can use `>` to quote text and `\`` to format inline code. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help for the details.

Comment: I don't really understand your question: The package already provides a LaTeX package `prodint`. However, in order for this package to work, you first have to copy the font files to the right directories. I don't think a LaTeX package (i.e. a LaTeX style file) can do this automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty bash script to copy the files into the local TeX tree and call the commands to activate the configuration. If you save the file as `installprodint` in the directory where you put `prodint.tgz`, run it using `sudo bash installprodint` from this directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
texdir=$(kpsewhich -expand-var='$TEXMFLOCAL' | sed 's/:.*//')
tar -xzf ./prodint.tgz
mkdir -p $texdir/fonts/map/dvips/prodint
cp prodint/*.map $texdir/fonts/map/dvips/prodint
mkdir -p $texdir/fonts/tfm/public/prodint
cp prodint/*.tfm $texdir/fonts/tfm/public/prodint
mkdir -p $texdir/fonts/type1/public/prodint
cp prodint/*.pfb $texdir/fonts/type1/public/prodint
mkdir -p $texdir/tex/latex/prodint
cp prodint/*.sty $texdir/tex/latex/prodint
rm -rf prodint
mktexlsr
updmap-sys --enable Map=prodint.map
```

The cleaner way is to build a Debian package (also usable with Ubuntu) that installs the font and the necessary style files. See [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete) how to make a Debian/Ubuntu package.

I wonder why the package is not on CTAN. Maybe you could ask the author of the package to put the package on CTAN so it can be included in TeX Live.

Comment: the author of the package has given his blessing for it to be added to ctan.  the ctan team is rushed off its feet, just now, and hasn't managed to sort out the bundle and install the files

Comment: @anon thanks for getting the author's permission.  So I suppose it will be pushed to future versions of texlive?  How do I follow up on its status?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I just wanted to point out that the `prodint` package is now available in [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/prodint) and it is as easy to install as any other package. Just do `usepackage` and use either `\Prodi` or `\PRODI` command. E.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{prodint}

\begin{document}
\[ \Prodi_a^b{(1 + f(t)\mathrm{d}t)} \]
\[ \PRODI_a^b{(1 + f(t)\mathrm{d}t)} \]
\end{document}
```

You will get:

[image: Prodint example]